# Sweave barplot label alignment

Tags: sweave

when I compile a horizontal barplot in sweave, I get inconsistent justification for long labels (not right justified). However, when I export the barplot with RStudio, the labels are correctly aligned.

How can I get labels correctly right justified?

Thanks.

[EDIT]
The problem is when latex includes the pdf where sweave generated the barplot. In such pdf, the labels are correctly aligned.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried anything (a little code=MWE)?

Comment: The problem is when latex includes the pdf where sweave generated the barplot. In such pdf, the labels are correctly aligned. @Sebastiano

Comment: Try to add a picture or your .tex. I have not understand much. Don't worry if there is any errors. You are welcome.